# CRM Job Maintenance Logs in SQL Database

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, crm, maintenance-plan

We are managing our CRM 2013 (on-premise) maintenance jobs via the "CRM 2011 Job Editor" (downloadable from Codeplex here: https://crmjobeditor.codeplex.com/).

We have set a reindexing job to run daily, however we would like to double-check if the job might not run on certain days due to errors or whatnot.

Do you know if there are any written logs of the CRM maintenance jobs, if it's writing any history logs into the SQL database somewhere?

I see from CRM Trace when certain performance task is initiated, however keeping trace on at all time consumes a lot of disk space... just wondering if CRM by design writes any log history of maintenance plan into SQL database.

Comment: i know only LinQ to SQL (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx), why need use crmjobeditor? Try LinqQ make easier work.

Comment: Codeplex Repo moves to GitHub: https://github.com/seanmcne/DynamicsCRMOnPremJobEditor

Answer (score 0):

The System Job entity (schema name: asyncoperation) is where I'd start.  That entity has a Job Type field and one of the values is Index Management.  Check that entity's table.

Comment: I looked up the AsyncOperationBase table. Saw the 'OperationType' field and the field description here: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmattwittemann/archive/2009/12/07/the-asyncoperationbase-table-58-what-are-all-those-records-anyway-63
The performance task that we want to query is 'Re-index All' and 'Index Management' which is type 15, 30 unfortunately the query is returning nothing...
SELECT * FROM dbo.AsyncOperationBase WHERE OperationType IN (15,30)