# What is the default schedule for the default CRM 2011 maintenance jobs?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a CRM 2011 installation that experiences a huge spike in I/O at a certain time of day (11 am).
I have a good suspicion that it's the default Rebuild Index Job.

Everything is at default values, and the latest applied update is RU13.
Sql is sql 2008 r2, sp1.

I've found this [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crminthefield/2012/04/26/avoid-performance-issues-by-rescheduling-crm-2011-maintenance-jobs/) and also other sources suggesting updating the default job's schedule to run at night, or not at all.

But I haven't been able to find what is the default schedule for these default CRM jobs. I understand they are executing daily, but when? 
at 1am, 1pm, 1h after service start?

Also, is there a way to view execution history?

Comment: Probably a good question for Sean in [codeplex](https://crmjobeditor.codeplex.com) or [PFE blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36270106/7920473) also didn’t work

Comment: New link: https://github.com/seanmcne/DynamicsCRMOnPremJobEditor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Dynamics CRM 2011 Asynchronous Service regularly executes multiple internal maintenance jobs for each organization (database) and that these are scheduled initially at the time of organization creation on default frequencies (daily, monthly, etc.). Hopefully, you're also aware of the need to reschedule these jobs to execute during non-peak usage hours so as to minimize impact on system performance

You can find more details in this [MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crminthefield/2013/02/07/more-juicy-details-on-dynamics-crm-2011-asynchronous-services-maintenance-jobs/)

The interesting comment there from Austin give you some insight.

> MSCRM_CONFIG.[dbo].ScalegroupOrganizationMaintenanceJobs table keeps track of LastResultCode and LastRunTime

[Useful query:](http://stuffaboutcrm.blogspot.com/2016/06/script-to-retrieve-maintenance-jobs.html?m=1)

```
select
LastRunTime,
CASE OperationType
       WHEN 14 THEN 'DeletionService'
       WHEN 15 THEN 'IndexManagement'
       WHEN 30 THEN 'ReindexAll'
       WHEN 32 THEN 'CleanupInactiveWorkflowAssemblies'
       WHEN 40 THEN 'GoalRollup'
END OperationType, OperationType,
enabled, ExecutionTime,LastResultCode,LastResultData
,MaintenanceWindowEndTime,MaintenanceWindowStartTime, ModifiedOn
,NextRunTime,RecurrencePattern, RecurrenceStartTime, StartedOn, State, IsDeleted

from ScaleGroupOrganizationMaintenanceJobs
order by LastRunTime desc
```

Comment: Yes! That's the link I was trying to find. Upvote for finding it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I remember finding the answer to this a long time ago, but I can't find the link now. The jobs' default schedule depends on *when in the day you originally installed Dynamics*. IIRC, the jobs are scheduled to start 24 hours after installation. This is kind of a silly default since most would install it in the middle of the workday, but that's why they recommend that you change it to be more appropriate for your business schedule.